# User cannot add an image to a publishing page

Tags: 2007, publishing-page, image

One of our users is editing a publishing page. She has full controll of both the page and the image library that she wants to use. Still, when she try to add an image ("Edit Picture" under Page Image on the page) she is not able to choose an image in the "Select an Image - Webpage Dialog" window. Nothing happens when she tries to mark an image. She can not select an image. She is using IE 9. I use IE11 and have no problems with this operation.

I have never seen this before. Has anyone an idea of what is causing this?

Comment: The user has now updated her browser to IE 11 and the problems persists. does anyone have an idea of what could be causing it? I have never seen anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the browser version that is her issue.  Can she upgrade to the newer version of IE, or try Chrome/Firefox to see if it works?

Comment: Thank's for your reply! She has upgraded to IE11 and the problem persists.